# How to change the frame of a container inside container view when button is pressed in base VC?

Tags: ios, swift, containers

I have a Container View inside a base view controller. When the viewWillApear I change the frame of the container view so that it does not apeare on screen. On the base VC there is a button which when pressed should "bring up" the VC which was moved down before. How can I achieve this?

**I have tried inside the IBAction for the button in the base VC to call the method used to change frames but when I do this I get a runTimeError:**

```
    @objc func CommentsTapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Bring up the comments view and load all data into it.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.commentsDelegate!.updateCommentSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 227))//This method in implemented in the base VC given that it is specified in the protocol for the commentsVC
    })
}
```

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Implementation of method:

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController, CommentCellDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var commentsContainer: UIView!

func updateCommentSheet(frame: CGRect) {
    commentsContainer.frame = frame
}
```

Comment: what error ???? where `CommentsTapped` is , share full context ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan see edit...

Comment: how do you use `commentsDelegate` share full context of the problem

Comment: check whether `commentsDelegate` is nil / not

Comment: it is. I am unsure how to pass it over i am doig but get error:             VC.commentsDelegate = self, Ambiguous use of 'commentsDelegate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is this:

Create a var and set it equal to the ViewController in your prepare method. Now you have access and can control the second view controller/class from your base one. So, if your sheet delegates are set up properly (i.e. ViewController.xdelegate = self) then you can call it like this:

```
self.secondVC.xdelegate.updateFrame(frame: newFrame)
```